# How to get the rows value in php as all rows name is same?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Please find the below code to add new rows as well as delete row button. using that script we can enable only 5 rows after that "Add More" button automatically disable. Now the problem is, if I click on submit button php page should print all rows values. but I am not able to print all rows values as all rows name are same (input_box_one[] and input_box_two[] ). hence I am not able to get all rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){

                                $('.del').live('click',function(){
                                        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
                                });

                                $('.add').live('click',function(){
                                        var i = 1;

                                        var appendTxt = "<tr><td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td>Pronto Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";
                                        $("tr:last").before(appendTxt);

var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
if(inputs == 17){
document.getElementById("countButton").disabled = true;
}
$i++

                                });
                        });
                </script>
         </head>

    <body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

                <table id="options-table">
                        <tr>
                                <td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type="text"   name="input_box_one[]" /></td>
                                <td>Pronto Title:</td><td><input type="text"     name="input_box_two[]" /></td>
                                <td><input type="button" class='del' value='Delete' /></td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="count" value="<?php $i; ?>">
                        </tr>

<?php
        echo "<tr><td><input id=\"countButton\" type=\"button\" class=\"add\" value=\"Add More\"/></td><td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\"></td></tr>";
?>


                </table>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could anyone please help on this.

thanks in advance.

Editing the question:

Hi,

In the script i need to enter Pronto ID exactly 12 character. if it's less/more than 12 it should echo the message to enter 12 character. what code should i add to this line? please help me.

```
var appendTxt = "<tr><td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td>Pronto Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print the $_POST varaible on php page like

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Than you will get the idea of posted inputs.afterword you have use the foreach method.

Comment: Hi, in the script i need to enter Pronto ID exactly 12 character. if it's less/more than 12 it should echo the message to enter 12 character. what code should i add to this line? please help me. "var appendTxt = "<tr><td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td>Pronto Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";"

Comment: var appendTxt = "<tr><td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' maxlength='12' onChange='limitText(this,12);' /></td><td>Pronto Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>"

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText(limitField, limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length < limitNum) {
        alert('Pront ID length should be 12 character');
    }
}
</script>

Answer (score 7):

```
foreach ($_POST['input_box_one'] as $v) {

   echo $v . '<--- i am your value<br>';

}

Result
------
inputboxvalue1
inputboxvalue2
inputboxvalue3
etc....
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. but i need to print all the values at a time. Could you please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?  Can you give an example?  This code above will loop through each value and print it out.  So it will give you all the values.

Comment: Glad to help.  Can you click the checkmark to the left of my answer to indicate it is correct.  Thanks.  :) @MAHADEVASWAMYHN

Comment: @ Notorious Pet0: Hi, in the script i need to enter Pronto ID exactly 12 character. if it's less/more than 12 it should echo the message to enter 12 character. what code should i add to this line? please help me. "var appendTxt = "<tr><td>Pront ID:</td><td><input type='text' name='input_box_one[]' /></td><td>Pronto Title:</td> <td><input type='text' name='input_box_two[]' /></td> <td><input type='button' class='del' value='Delete' /></td></tr>";"